# How to make caddy redirect/use my DNS server?

Tags: proxy, dns, forward, caddy

I have a DNS server in my local network running on `192.168.1.1` where I've defined the following entry:

```
something.home 192.168.1.10
```

and I'd like to make `caddy` running (in a container) on the host with address `192.168.1.10` to be able to use that DNS server when resolving local addresses.

For now I have the following in my `Caddyfile`

```
something.home:80 {
    proxy / 192.168.1.10:9999 {
            transparent
        }

    errors stderr
    tls off
}
```

I'd like to have:

```
something.home:80 {
    proxy / something:9999 {
            transparent
        }

    errors stderr
    tls off
}
```

to redirect to server actually listening on `192.168.1.10:9999` inside a container named `something`.

Can I do that or is there a different approach?

Comment: Is the only reason you need this because you need proper (original) Host header to be transferred to :9999 ? Or because ip address is dynamic and you don't want to hardcode it in caddy configuration?

Comment: I don't want to hardcode it. If I change the IP of this box I'll need to change it both at the DNS and in Caddy configuration.

Comment: Can't you just use 127.0.0.1 in caddy config?

Comment: Ok I think I've described my scenario incorrectly: the problem is that I run `something` container on this host (with 192.168.1.10 IP address) and caddy would need to know about it. I can put it in the same docker-compose file and add an alias to it but I'd prefer to separate those.

Comment: (putting it all in one docker-compose file is probably the best way to proceed, but let's try) What OS are you running docker on (and do you need it to be portable for other users)?

Comment: On Linux (Ubuntu). What do you mean portable for other users?

Comment: I meant do you need it to work for someone on Mac/Win (I asked because some solutions might be OS specific)

Comment: This might help :https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-35-connect-to-a-database-running-on-your-docker-host , it is a similar use case

Comment: @DusanBajic alright, I don't need it to be portable for other OSes.